# Spresense拡張ボードと電子ペーパー

Tags: spresense

Spresenseメインボードに拡張ボードを接続し、温湿度気圧センサーBME280をI2C接続、電子ペーパー (E-Ink 7.5インチ Red/Black/White) を [Universal e-Paper Raw Panel Driver Shield for Arduino / NUCLEO](https://www.waveshare.com/e-Paper-Shield.htm) を介して、SPI 4Wire接続して、電子ペーパーに温湿度、気圧を表示することを試みています。

Arduino IDEのシリアルモニターでは、温湿度気圧センサーの値が表示され、取得できています。
[E-Paper Shield](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/E-Paper_Shield) のDemo Codeを使って、プログラムを実行しましたが、電子ペーパーの初期化やクリアは動作するのですが、Stringに変換したセンサーの値が書き込まれません。

SpresenseをArduino MEGAに置き換えて、同様に実行すると、表示できました。
いろいろ調べてみましたが、Spresenseで電子ペーパーに表示できない原因がわかりません。ご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか。ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

＜推測1＞
以前のSpresenseのドキュメントでは、E-Paperの記述があったのですが、現在は見当たりません。電子ペーパーに対応していないのかもしれません。

＜推測2＞
SpresenseのSPI通信はマスターモードのみと記述がありました。Arduinoやラズパイは双方向通信可能なので、これが原因かもしれません。Spresenseも双方向通信になれば、電子ペーパーが使えるようになるのかもしれません。

Comment: コードを提示しましょう

Comment: SPIのマスターモードと双方向は関係ありません。SPIの信号のMOSI、MISOは "Master Out Slave In"、”Master In Slave Out"の意味で、デバイスのどちらがマスターかでつなぐ信号の接続が変わります。ところで、E-Paper は使ったことがないのですが、Ether Shield を使おうとしたときに、Spresense の CS がハード制御のため、うまく動かないことがありました。オシロでCSの信号の動きを見ればそれが原因かわかります。関係ないかもしれませんが、ご参考まで。

Comment: ご参考までに、Ether Shield のときのやりとりです。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57036/spresense-arduino%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e3%82%a4%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b5%e3%83%8d%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%83%a2%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6/57041#57041

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。
オシロでCSの信号を見ると、書き込み時にバースト波形になっており、少しもLOWになっていませんでした。
原因が分かってよかったです。有益な情報をありがとうございました。
なんとかLOWで書き込めるように、いろいろ試してみようと思います。